# Keras batch normalization for shared layers

Tags: python, keras, batch-normalization

In previous keras version I used batch normalization parameter mode=2 to use shared modules in my network. After upgrading this parameter no longer exists and when I'm using batch normalization the network doesn't seem to learn.